# Programatically switching tabs using selectedViewController property

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I've used search already, haven't found an answer.

Trying to switch like this:

```
[self. tabBarController.selectedViewController OptionsViewContorller];
```

and like this:

```
 [self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = self.tabBarController.viewControllers     objectAtIndex:3];
```

but it doesn't work, i also tried and advice to change

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex
```

but it only changes at tab bar not a view.

Comment: which version of iOS sdk you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];
```

Comment: it just changes selected icon it tab bar but it doesn't change view.

Comment: @HorheGarcia is the icon changed to correct. if the icon and the tab index is right, check the selected view controller. Does you tap the tab index, it behaves right?

Comment: i found the problem, my tab tab is situated in another controller. From that controller it works ok, how can i access it from another controller?

Comment: @HorheGarcia use delegation pattern to interact between controllers

Answer (score 2):

// this code i am using to switch to tabbar view controller 0, first view controller.

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

UIViewController *controller = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    [((UINavigationController*)controller) popToRootViewControllerAnimated:false];
}

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:true];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// viewControllerIndex is an int describing the position of the viewController
// in the tab bar array index
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:viewControllerIndex];
```

Comment: it just changes selected icon it tab bar but it doesn't change view.

Comment: If the tab bar icon is changing it sounds like it IS changing the view controller - are you sure the views in your tab bar are **distinct** enough to recognise them changing?

Comment: they are absolutely different. why it may be so? icon becomes active but views doesn't change..

Comment: its best if you refer to Tabster, included with ios documentation. there must be something you are doing wrong.

Comment: i found the problem, my tab tab is situated in another controller. From that controller it works ok, how can i access it from another controller?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch from your `UITabBarController` class, you have to write this code in `-viewDidAppear:animated:`

```
[((UIViewController *) self.viewControllers[0]).tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

for **swift 4+**

you have to get reference to the tab before the view was presented

```
let tab = self.presentingViewController as! UITabBarController
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:{ 
     tab.selectedIndex = 2
})
```