# TabBarController selectedViewController Doesn't Change the View

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have already read:
[Programatically switching tabs using selectedViewController property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633420/programatically-switching-tabs-using-selectedviewcontroller-property)

I am using XCode 10 and Swift 4.2
I run 2 lines of code in a ViewController.ViewDidAppear which is assigned to the second Tab Bar Item (index 1). Below myAppsTabBarController is a swift class that subclasses UITabBarController and has a static variable called myTabBarController that is assigned to self.

```
myAppsTabBarController.myTabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3
myAppsTabBarController.myTabBarController?.selectedViewController = myAppsTabBarController.myTabBarController?.viewControllers[3]
```

The first line works as I can see the 4th tab bar item light up (like it is selected.) The second line doesn't seem to work as the view doesn't update to the 4th tab. I have printed out myAppsTabBarController.myTabBarController?.viewControllers?.count and it is 4 so I know it exists. Any idea why the second line isn't changing the user's view? Thank you.

Comment: Did you call it in the main thread?

Comment: For me, both lines are working fine individually. Even, changing the view controller also updates the selectedIndex property accordingly and vice versa.

Comment: Can you please share the code for how the viewControllers are setup?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what you mean by main thread. When my app starts up the 0 index tab bar item is the view that is presented. When the user clicks on the tab bar item at index 1 if certain user data isn't set up (which i check for at the end of ViewDidLoad) then I'd like to send the user to tab bar item at index 3. So this code sits in a function called at the end of ViewDidLoad.

Comment: I will add that the second line does seem to encompass the function of the first line so I guess I could drop the .selectedIndex = 3 line.

Comment: I also found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966301/uitabbarcontroller-selectedindex-and-selectedviewcontroller-do-not-work

But moving the code to ViewDidAppear didn't change anything.

Comment: I edited the original post to point out that I am referencing the tab bar (myTabBarController) as a static variable inside the UITabBarController subclass I made from a ViewController. So maybe that has something to do with why it isn't working?

Comment: I'm wondering if there needs to be a line of code after the .selectedViewController call ? Something with a "present" type of command?

Comment: So I tried:
  
  myAppsTabBarController.myTabBarController?.selectedViewController?.present(myAppsTabBarController.myTabBarController?.viewControllers?[3]!, animated: true, completion: nil)

But I got an uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException reason: Application tried to present modally an active controller
Am I getting closer? (PS- I don't know why the 4 spaces rule won't work to define that line of code in this comment.)